# CircleCI Deploy to AWS S3: What is the path to my files?

Tags: amazon-s3, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci-2.0

My Deployment fails in CircleCI

In my config file, I have the following:

```
  deploy:
docker:
  - image: circleci/python:2.7-jessie
working_directory: ~/circleci-docs
steps:
  - run:
      name: Install awscli
      command: sudo pip install awscli
  - run:
      name: Deploy to s3
      command: aws s3 sync <filepath> s3://BUCKET-NAME/ --delete
```

It fails on the deploy and I get the error

> The user provided path does not exist

I have tried a few different file paths:

> /
>
> ~/applicationname
>
> ~/working-directoryname
>
> ~/

But they all give the same error.

Then I tried using the working_directory name and also `/home/circleci/working_directory_name`

Both seem to succeed, yet no files appear in the bucket

What is the path that I should be using for the filepath?

Comment: Do you have `checkout` step? https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#checkout

Comment: thhanks @ittus. It was in the build but not the deploy. Adding it fixed my issue.